# Regex only one number

Tags: regex, vb.net

How can I give with regular expressions, that only one numeric character can be entered?

```
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("[^0-9]+")
```

Comment: Regular expressions have nothing to do with WPF. This is a VB.NET question

Comment: What do you actually want to do? The pattern you posted searches for *non* numeric characters, the opposite of what you ask. Why not search for *numbers* and count the results, eg `Regex.Matches(input,@"\d").Count`? Or are you looking for something to put in a regular expression validator?

Comment: Accepting only one digit you can use `^\d$`. Accepting multiple digits you can use `^\d+$`

Comment: @ctwheels In .NET, `\d` means a Unicode digit, e.g. ௬, so it is necessary to either use `[0-9]` or RegExOptions.ECMAScript, which has [other requirements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @AndrewMorton that's correct, but assuming that the OP doesn't want to accept Unicode digits. If ASCII-only is the aim it should be `^[0-9]$` or `^[0-9]+$`

Comment: @ctwheels I saw the `"[^0-9]+"` in the question, so it seemed reasonable to point it out just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely no need for Regular Expressions in this case. Instead, set the [MaxLength](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.maxlength(v=vs.110).aspx) of your TextBox to 1 and then in the [TextChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event use the following code:

```
If TextBox1.Text.Length > 0 AndAlso Not Char.IsDigit(TextBox1.Text(0)) Then
    'Invalid input
End If
```

Comment: It needs a check if the string length is 1. In VB.Net non-strict mode, `Char.IsDigit` checks only the first character in a string. In C# that results in a compile error.

Comment: Not sure if you misunderstood me. The correct check would be more like `If TextBox1.Text.Length <> 1 OrElse`. As a side note, `Char.IsDigit` is True for most of the Unicode digits in other languages too http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm

Answer (score 1):

To check if a string is a decimal digit (from 0 to 9) in VB:

```
If string Like "[0-9]" Then
```

---

The `#` pattern matches [Unicode digits in other languages](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm) too (similar to `Char.IsDigit`):

```
If "９" Like "#" Then
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("^[^0-9]+$")
```

By adding a `^` before and a dollar behind you can check on a exact string.

You can remove the plus if you need exactly one number. Else it's zero or one.

Comment: The [^0-9] matches non-digits and the + suffix matches one or more. If the OP wanted to match only 1 digit, the appropriate RegEx would be: ^\d$

Answer (score 0):

Your regex `[^0-9]+` matches any non-zero number of anything **except** decimal digits.
Your goal seems to be matching a single decimal digit.
Depending on the regex flavor the corresponding regex is

```
[0-9]
```

or, with more powerful flavors

```
\d
```